# « Mégoïsme » et « poublier » : de quoi s'agit-il, comment les décrit-on ?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation, figure-de-style, jeux-de-mots, homonymes

> **Mégoïsme** *n. m.* Écraser n'importe où. ([Ville de Montréal](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/portal/page?_pageid=9257,143268754&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL))
>   **Poublier** *v.* Oublier que la poubelle ou le bac existent. ([Ville de
>   Montréal](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/portal/page?_pageid=9257,143268720&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL))

Faut croire qu'on s'amuse avec la langue et on a peint ça sur des trottoirs à différents endroits de la Ville. Il s'agit d'un [jeu de mots](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_mots) sous forme de « fausse définition ». Évidemment, on reconnaît le mot [*mégot*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9got) vu l'homophonie en début du premier mot alors qu'on évoque le mot *poubelle* dans le deuxième.

- De quel type de jeu de mot/figure de style et de présentation du jeu
  de mots s'agit-il ; existe-t-il un nom pour un nom qui contienne un nom ou pour le nom contenu dans un nom ?
- Peut-on décrire précisément dans une phrase par quel procédé on part
  du mot évoqué pour en arriver au mot qui constitue la vedette en
  s'appuyant sur des termes comme *homophonie, syllabe, préfixe* ou un
  vocabulaire plus clair, comme si on s'adressait à quelqu'un qui ne
  connaît pas ces mots ?

  > On a préfixé le mot *égoïsme* de la première lettre du mot *mégot* de
  >   sorte qu'on a homophonie avec ce mot dans les deux premières syllabes
  >   du résultat *mégoïsme*.
- Comment nomme-t-on ou qualifie-t-on la
  différence d'homophonie entre *mégoïsme* et *poublier* ?

Answer (score 3):

On appelle ce genre de trouvailles des mots-valises.  C'est assez répandu dans la pub, je crois.  C'est rarement très heureux comme jeu de mots et je ne trouve pas ces deux-là particulièrement réussis.

*Mégoïsme* est un substantif que l'agence de pub chargée de la campagne, j'imagine, définit par un verbe.  C'est pas terrible, je trouve, mais bon, j'ergote et je mégote.

Quant à *poublier*, avant de lire ta question, j'avais pensé d'abord à un composé de *poubelle* et de *publier* que j'allais mettre dans le même sac que *journalope* ou *presstitute* en anglais.

Ceci dit, la campagne est peut-être efficace.

Comment: Tu *mergotes* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sur le premier point: il s'agit d'un *amalgame lexical* communément appelé *mot-valise*.

Voir https://www.cairn.info/revue-langages-2011-3-page-75.htm